# Google Drive API Rest Python is not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, pipenv

I'm trying to follow this guideline:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python

Then, I have installed pipenv and google-api-python-client, I've turned on the Drive API.

So, after running the following command:

```
pipenv run python quickstart.py
```

It's opened a browser, asked for permissions, but the app got stucked with following message:

```
    ...

    If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

What should I do? I would like to list Google Drive files. I've tried running Python 2.7, but I had the same problem.

My Pipfile:

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[packages]

requests = "*"
google-api-python-client = "*"


[dev-packages]



[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```

Comment: Where exactly in the flow did the app got stuck. Was it after your "allowed" permissions? This [github post](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/wiki/How-to-get-OAuth-access-token-in-console%3F) about the OAuth setup might help.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I gave the permissions, but the app got stuck. Tks, I'm gonna take a look.